# Select2 don't show tags at first rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, jquery-select2

I have this select:

```
<select id='visits_type' value={this.state.current_company.visits_type} onChange={this.handleChange} multiple='multiple'  className='form-control'>
    <option value="Visita Presencial">Visita Presencial</option>
    <option value="Telefone/Ligação">Telefone/Ligação</option>
    <option value="Email">Email</option>    
    <option value="WhatsApp">WhatsApp</option>
    <option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>  
    <option value="Site/Formulário de Contato">Site/Formulário de Contato</option>
```

The selected values are loaded from the database and injected in the select with react.js through the **value={this.state.current_company.visits_type}** statement. It works fine:

[image]

But I want this to look Select2 style, so I do:

```
$('#visits_type').select2({ tags: true, multiple: true).on('change', self.handleChange);
```

My problem is that when I do apply the select2 to the select, it won't show the tags of the already 'selected' elements unless I insert another tag/option.

At first, it will show nothing (no tags):

[image]

If I click the select it will show my 3 allready selected options, but still no tags:

[image]

If I click any option it will add/remove the selected option AND WILL SHOW TAGS:

[image]

I want that thoose tags appear since the very first rendering, not only after I open the select options and click one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the value via `$(...).select2('val', values)`.

```js
$('#example').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select a month',
    tags: true,
    multiple: true
});

var selectedValues = [['JAN','FEB']];
$('#example').select2("val", selectedValues);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<select id="example" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="JAN">January</option>
    <option value="FEB">February</option>
    <option value="MAR">March</option>
    <option value="APR">April</option>
    <option value="MAY">May</option>
    <option value="JUN">June</option>
    <option value="JUL">July</option>
    <option value="AUG">August</option>
    <option value="SEP">September</option>
    <option value="OCT">October</option>
    <option value="NOV">November</option>
    <option value="DEC">December</option>
</select>
```